# why x86 assembly function call first argument is rbp - 4 rather then rbp + 4

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64

```cpp
int square(int num, int i2) {
    return num * num;
}
```

```
square(int, int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        imul    eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

we know stack is grow from high address to low address, i see book when function call happens, the stack may like function argument, then return address, then old ebp. but why rbp - 4 is the first argument address, rather then rbp + 4, since the argument keeped in high address

can you explain for me?

Comment: The first argument is EDI and the second is ESI. The fact that they are temporary stored on the stack is another story.

Comment: Old 32-bit code uses a worse more simplistic calling convention where args are only passed on the stack, put there by the caller.  x86-64 System V, the caller didn't reserve space to spill the register args, the compiler chose the red zone.  (In Windows x64, a debug build would spill them to the shadow space, starting at [rsp+8] on function entry, or [rbp+16] after setting up a stack frame.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64 bit ABI - first 6 patameters are passed in the **registers** not on the stack.

so to see how the parameter is taken from the stack you need to have more of them:

```
int goo(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5, int n6, int n7) {
    return n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 +n7;
}
```

and the code:

```
        add     edi, esi
        add     edi, edx
        add     edi, ecx
        add     edi, r8d
        lea     eax, [rdi+r9]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        ret
```

As you see the parameter `n7` is being taken from the stack `DWORD PTR [rsp+8]`

On 32 bit system:

```
goo:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+12]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+16]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+20]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+24]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+28]
        ret
```

all parameters are taken from the stack.

> why x86 assembly function call first argument is rbp - 4 rather then
> rbp + 4

Because you compiled it without optimiations and compiler has provided automatic storage for those parameters which were passed in the registers.

Same code for x86-64 compiled without the optimizations:

```
goo:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], ecx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], r8d
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], r9d
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        add     edx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
        add     edx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        add     edx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        add     edx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        add     edx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp+16]
        add     eax, edx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

[image: (C)copyright - https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/]
(C)copyright - https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/ posted without any permission

Comment: thank you for answering me, i read a book which is too old<twenty years ago>, tell me arguments are all saved above the return address<RBP + 8> in your picture, i was a bit confusing, thanks, i understand

Answer (score 0):

The register `rbp` stores the current address of the stack. As you have written yourself

> we know stack is grow from high address to low address

so to allocate memory for parameters that are local variables of the function the register `rbp` is decremented by sizes of the types of the parameters

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
```

`rbp + 4` addresses memory of the caller that does not belong to the function. As it is seen in this simple function arguments are passed to the function through registers `edi` and `esi` that are stored in the parameters (local variables) of the function. If the number of arguments is greater than the number of registers used by the compiler to store arguments then in this case to access arguments within the functon the  a positive value can be added to `rbp` to access arguments stored in the stack by the caller. Passing arguments through registers is more efficent.

Comment: Actually `rbp+4` does belong to this function.  After `push rbp` / `mov rbp, rsp`, the dword at `[rbp+4]` is the high half of the saved RBP value.  (We need to restore the caller's RBP before returning, so we can't actually overwrite that space, or the return address at bytes `[rbp+8 .. 15]`, but that region of stack space is actually owned by this function and can be modified; the caller can't assume anything about what'll be left there upon return.)

Comment: Your real point is correct, though, that `dword [rbp+4]` is not a viable place for spilling a register arg after this setup, so instead it uses the red-zone.